# how do I retrieve a list of order states

Tags: magento2, collection, order-state

I'm looking for a way to fetch all possible order states in Magento 2. I found a way to fetch all Order Statuses but there doesn't seem to be a collection for order states.

Any ideas on how to retrieve them?

So far I'm only able to access them indirectly by using the join states() function on the order status resource model collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

   use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory;

   class OrderStatus
   {
      /**
      * @var CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory
      */
      protected $orderStatusCollectionFactory;

      /**
       * @param CollectionFactory $orderStatusCollectionFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
      CollectionFactory $orderStatusCollectionFactory
      ) {
          $this->orderStatusCollectionFactory = $orderStatusCollectionFactory;
      }

      /**
       * Get order status options
       *
       * @return array
       */
       public function getOrderStatusOptions(): array
       {
           $options = $this->orderStatusCollectionFactory->create()
           ->toOptionArray();
           return $options;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Sorry looking for states not statuses